# interpreting stty output to start connection with hyperterminal

Tags: linux, serial-port, rs232, hyperterminal

I am trying to communicate between an embedded device which runs linux and a PC which runs windows xp over a RS232 connection. On windows I use Hyperterminal, but I don't know which settings I should use.
I have to set

- Bits per second
- Data bits
- Parity
- Stop bits
- Flow control

On the linux device i ran `stty` to find out the settings on that side. I do NOT want to change those settings the linux device, but only read them out. But I have a hard time interpreting the output.

<strike>~$ stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a
    speed 9600 baud; rows 24; columns 80;
    intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
    eol2 = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
    lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
    -parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
    -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
    -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel
    opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
    isig icanon iext</strike>

`Bits per second` will presumably have to be set to 9600, but how do I have to interpret the remaining output from stty?

Edit:

Okay, i did a little more. Looking if `getty` is running:

```
~# ps | grep getty
 1557 root      1884 S    /sbin/getty 115200 ttyS2
 1558 root      1884 S    /sbin/getty 38400 tty1
 1600 root      2636 S    grep getty
```

I assume this means that I am listening on the device `ttyS2` and it also seems to indicate the baudrate as `115200`. Now I ran `stty` to see the settings:

```
~# stty -F /dev/ttyS2 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 24; columns 80;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^X; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon
-ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0
ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop
-echoprt -echoctl -echoke
```

Now trying to use this in Hyperterminal, I would assume the following settings:

- Bits per second: 115200
- Data bits: 8 (because of cs8)
- Parity: None (because of -parenb)
- Stop bits: 1 (because of -cstopb)
- Flow control: none (because of -crtscts and -ixon)

But it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 8 bits, no parity, one stop bit, software flow control. This comes from:

"cs8" means 8 data bits. "-crtscts" means no hardware flow control. "ixon" means soft flow control. "-cstop" means one stop bit.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. It's still not working though. Might have to check the cables etc.

Comment: Is something listening on that port? Do you have `getty` or the like running? Otherwise, you're connecting to a port that no process is listening to.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I added my question a bit, but unfortunately it's still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I would try rebooting and not messing with the device at all. Let `getty` manage it. You may have confused getty. Also, getting typically expects hardware flow control.

Comment: Okay, it turned out to be a wrong connection on our circuit board. But I will mark this as the answer, because it's exactly what I asked.